# Particular Map insert code takes time - overhead

Tags: c++, dictionary, overhead

I am using map insert and find operations in my project. But only a particular insertion of map is taking more time for execution. The code is below

```
std::map<ThreadID,int>::iterator itr1 = paddingMap->m_map.find(threadID); 
        if (itr1 != paddingMap->m_map.end())
            itr1->second = paddingSize;
        else
            paddingMap->m_map.insert(pair<ThreadID,int>(threadID,paddingSize));
```

The above lines are in a call back function which will be called many times. Without these lines it takes 150 ms and with this piece of code it takes 2350 ms. But i have used the same map in another place where it is not taking more overhead.

What is the issue in this ?

**Update:**

1.My current example has only one thread. (Hence the number of pair in map is only one).

2.The value in the pair is modified from two call backs functions , which are synchronized.

3.The number of calls will be around 80K calls .

4. Modifying on the second call back function only causing the overhead.! Not the first callback.

Comment: Do you need to iterate through the collection in an ordered way, if not maybe try unordered_map.

Comment: Why not `m_map[threadID] = paddingSize;`?

Comment: Not sure. But you can replace all of the above code with `paddingMap[threadID] = paddingSize;`  Also how many elements in your map and how many calls to the above in your time-interval?

Comment: The code was like paddingMap[threadID] = paddingSize;  only ..!!! Since it caused the same overhead , I tried the above specified lines. @WojciechFrohmberg: The number of pairs that map holds will be less only ( <20) so only i dint choose unordered map.

Comment: @juanchopanza How will that speed things up ? I'm not saying you're wrong. My understanding is that the `[]` operator will just do the exact same thing (and that's where I may be wrong and would like to be enlightened).

Comment: @fjardon - that's the point, it is the same. Less code is usually better, (for a given value of better ;) )

Comment: @fjardon It won't do the exact same thing. It will have the same effect. But I am not suggesting it to speed things up (although it might.) I just don't like pointless code.

Comment: Just a guess time: Is your code multi-threaded? And is the above code protected by some sort of lock/mutex?

Comment: Is your code being executed by multiple concurrent threads? If so, this might be a false sharing issue (your code isn't extremely suspicious, but still). Also, if MT indeed, the map must be protected to avoid races. Is there a lock around its accesses?

Comment: @juanchopanza At least for g++, there will be no differences. I checked the headers...

Comment: Ya.. As my code needs to support multiple threads, the code block is protected by mutex lock/unlock ..

Comment: There you go. The overhead is not in the map, but in the mutex synchronization.

Comment: `operator[]` will speed it up in the case of `threadID` being absent, since you save a lookup.

Comment: @RahulJain when you tested without the above lines did you remove the mutex as well?

Comment: @Richard Critten : Yes.. I also tried without mutex.. Implementing mutex are as part of steps taken to remove overhead .. :(

Comment: @Barry : I uncommented the lookup part and checked the overhead on commenting the assignment/insertion part alone. At that point i dint get any overhead.. So the overhead is not in lookup.. It is in assignment/insertion into the map..

Comment: @RahulJain, are you implementing the mutex yourself?? and how was using a mutex supposed to remove overhead - what have you been using before? You should better add that part of the code to your question. Also, multithreading adds all sorts of overheads as threads now communicate through memory. for starters, is every entry in the map being accessed by one or many threads?

Comment: @fjardon I looked at the headers for gcc 4.8.2. Not surprisingly, there are differences.

Comment: @eran : please look at the update of the post

Comment: @RahulJain, I'd try to remove portions of the code and see what causes the pain: eliminate synchronization (since there's one thread); then restore synchronization and eliminate the map (since there's a single entry); then restore the map and run just one callback. One of those experiments should hopefully point you to the actual bottleneck.

Comment: I am not able to come to a conclusion on bottlenecks here.. It is working weird..!   There are three map updates in one callback function and one map update in another callback function.  If I have all the map updations in both call back function , the time is more than 3 seconds.. Weirdly , If i comment out any of the map update in any callback function , the time is 150 milli seconds.. I tried with and without mutex ,same result..

Comment: @all :  If i lookup and update the same element in a map for more than 80K times , will the execution become slow ??